# xpath could not recognize a tag

Tags: javascript, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to use xpath to scrape reddit posts from a forum. 
One of the functions I want the spider to achieve is to automatically go to the next page as soon as it finishes scrapping from the current page. 
The page html code looks like this:

```html
<span class="next-button"><a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/InteriorDesign/?count=975&amp;after=t3_8ol7yp" rel="nofollow next" >next &rsaquo;</a></span>
```

and I used the xpath selector as:
      **response.xpath("//a[@class = 'next-button']")**
but it didn't give me anything back. Can someone help me figure out why?

thanks!
Hao

Answer (score 1):

The `@class` attribute is on the `span` element and not the `a` link element. So change your XPath to

```
response.xpath("//span[@class = 'next-button']/a")
```

to select `a` or

```
response.xpath("//span[@class = 'next-button']/a/@href")
```

to get the link address.

Comment: Hi I used your expression. thanks for the response. However it still gives me empty result, not sure why...

Comment: This answer is fine given what you've posted in your question.  If it's not working for you, post more details to get further help.